# Regular expression to match only two numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have such string:

> something: 20 kg/ something: 120 kg

I have this regex `("[0-9]{1,2} kg", string)`, but it returns `20kg` both times. I need to return `20kg` only in first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\s+kg
```

The `(?<!...)` is a [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So it matches one or two digits *not* preceded by a digit. I also changed the literal space with one or more space chars.

Seeing you've asked Python questions, here's a demo in Python:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
string = 'something: 20 kg/ something: 120 kg'
print re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\s+kg', string)
```

which will print `['20 kg']`

#### edit

As @Tim mentioned, a word boundary `\b` is enough: `r'\b\d{1,2}\s+kg'`

Comment: @Meph, no, then you need to change `\s+` into `\s*` (`*` meaning 'zero or more').